# How to put different categories value on X-Axis with in high-chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use different datas to make different column bar charts. (same as line chart I can click little icon at bottom then chart changes) but I have a problem, each data have different categories at X-Axis, which means when ever I change the data, categories change with it.

I can't figure out how to do it, e.g.:

I have multiple data in a column bar charts:

`series: [{
   name: 'name',
   data: data,
   color: 'white'
   },
   {name: 'name',
   data: data,
   color: 'white'}]`

Also each data have different category

```
categories: cataTitle1,cataTitle2
```

I can't make categories change as data changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need multiple Axes and multiple series with Column Chart [Here is Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaheerahmed/V8cgE/)
You can also use multiple YAxis. [Highchart Demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes) can help you in details.

```
       series: [{
            name: 'Rainfall',
            color: '#4572A7',
            type: 'column',

            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#AA4643',
            xAxis: 1,
            data: [1016, 1016, 1015.9, 1015.5, 1012.3, 1009.5, 1009.6, 1010.2, 1013.1, 1016.9, 1018.2, 1016.7],
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            dashStyle: 'shortdot'

        }]
```

Comment: **thank u very much.** it will helps me to create my multiple YAxis.